# how to add image upload along with ajax jquery form submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, image-upload

I am submitting a form using ajax jquery. I would like to upload an image along with the other fields.

Is it possible to make changes to my present script to accomplish it or would I need to redo everything :-

My jquery is :-

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".submit").click(function () {
            var article_title = $("#article_title").val();
            var article_body = $("#article_body").val();

            var dataString = 'article_title=' + article_title + '&article_body=' + article_body;

            if (article_title == '' || article_body == '') {
                $('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
                $('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
            } else {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo site_url().'/main/submit_article'?>",
                    data: dataString,
                    success: function () {
                        //$('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
                        $('#article_form')[0].reset();
                        $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
                    }

                });
            }

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

My HTML form :-

```
<form name="article_form" id="article_form" class="article_form" method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" name="article_title" id="article_title" placeholder="Title for your article" /> <!--<input type="file" name="pic" />-->
    <br>
    <textarea rows="12" name="article_body" id="article_body" placeholder="Tell your story"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Post" class="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: you need jQuery.form plugin that will help

Comment: I didn't get you. It checks if the fields are empty. This is working as of now.

Comment: @DipeshParmar would I be able to integrate it with the script I have written without major changes

Comment: yes you can...http://malsup.com/jquery/form/  no major change is required..

Comment: @DipeshParmar hey I am not able to properly use malsup with codeigniter. It loads a separate page - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121370/ajax-form-upload-loading-a-new-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not to make use of `jQuery.form` plugin.

This plugin allows to handle file upload efficiently [**Check here**](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload).

**For clearing fields**

```
$(':input','#myform').not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
.val('')
.removeAttr('checked')
.removeAttr('selected');
```

Comment: Parmer Hi, cud u help me in clearing the form fields after form submission. I think clearForm should be used, but I am not sure how

Comment: I tried this :- var options = {
      clearForm: true
     } its not working

Comment: @StacyJ see my answer update..call it inside success call back

Comment: no its not working. I changed #myform to #myForm since the name and id of my form is myForm. I pasted it after $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
     //alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
    });

Comment: then I tried it putting after closing of $(document).ready(function() . still no luck

Comment: though the values are being inserted ointo the database and the file is being uploaded

Comment: @StacyJ hey bro pls update your question with new code so i can help better.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085937/how-to-clear-form-fields-and-print-a-success-message-after-ajax-form-submission

Answer (score 1):

Add **enctype="multipart/form-data"** into your form element.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you a time saver here, try:

uploadify http://www.uploadify.com/

or you could try:

Jquery Forms [malsup.com/jquery/form/](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)

If you need progress bar, multiple uploads, drag and drop 
 https://github.com/valums/file-uploader

Use these tools and plugins and save yourself the stress. Don't reinvent the wheels unless you have a better idea.