# How to clear form fields and print a success message after ajax form submission

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, form-submit

I am using  for form submit. I would like to know how can I clear form fields and print a success message after form submission.

I used 
    var options = (
        clearForm: true
    }

but it didn't work

My code :-

```
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 

    <script> 
        // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
            $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
                //alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
            }); 

        }); 
    </script> 

</head>

<body>
    <form id="myForm" name="myForm" action="comment.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
        <input type="text" name="name" />
        <br /> 
        <textarea name="comment"></textarea> 
        <br />
        <input type="file" value="Share a Pic" name="file" id="file" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" /> 
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: you can use form.reset() too to clear form fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked with the following code :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var options = { 
                clearForm: true,
                resetForm: true
            };
            // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
            $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
                //alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 

            }); 
            $('#myForm').ajaxForm(options);

        }); 
    </script>
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

Just guessing, but would'nt the native `form.reset()` do that ?

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
     $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
         this.reset();
         alert('success');
     }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `resetForm` for this.
Here is the docs http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#options-object

or cna use functions like `resetForm` and `clearForm` docs on http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#api

Or try simply:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
     $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
         success:function(){
               $('#myForm').reset();
         }
     }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `clearForm();` also `resetForm();`.

**Official Document** : http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#api

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
        $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
            //alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
            $(this).clearForm();
        }); 

    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be :

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
      $("#myForm").submit(function(){
         $("input[type='text']").val('');
         $("input[type='textarea']").val('');
         alert('Message');
      });
 });
```

Comment: OP using jQuery plugin so do not need for submit handler.