# ajax form upload loading a new page

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, codeigniter, file-upload

I had a similar question yesterday - cud not resolve the issue

I am uploading a form with file and other inputs and all that is working fine. But the problem is that it is loading a new page i.e

```
www.mywebsite.com/controller/function.
```

This is my code

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var options = { 
            clearForm: true,
            resetForm: true
        };
        // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
        $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
            //alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 

        }); 
        $('#myForm').ajaxForm(options);

    }); 
</script> 

</head>

<body>
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" action="/main/comment" method="post"         enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <br /> 
    <textarea name="comment"></textarea> 
    <br />
    <input type="file" value="Share a Pic" name="file" id="file" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" /> 
</form>
</body>
```

I removed "main/comment" from my action and added url in var option part :-

```
var options = { 
            url: "<?php echo site_url().'/main/comment' ?>",
            clearForm: true,
            resetForm: true
        };
```

but even this does not seem to work. Please help
Thanks

Comment: Just a tip, you can use site_url and base_url this way <?php echo site_url('main/comment') ?>

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the example shown [here](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxForm)

I think you need to do this:

```
function successFunction(){
    alert('Thank you');
}
$(document).ready(function() {
        var options = { 
            clearForm: true,
            resetForm: true,
            success: successFunction
        };
        $('#myForm').ajaxForm(options);
});
```

Comment: @StacyJ Are you getting any errors in your javascript console? Do you have a live demo of this so I can see what's going on?